# Loop over 2d array, error TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, for-loop

I need to loop with y 2d array but it gives me error, it tells me: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot.py", line 18, in 
    y[k][j] = y[k][j]+1
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
jo =[20,30,40,50,60,70]
for k in jo:
    x=[]
    mo = str(k)
    migo = "".join(["./",mo,"/result_no"])
    with open(migo) as f:
        for line in f:
            x.append(float(line))
    y = [jo][0]*120
 #   print(y) 
    for i in range(len(x)):
        j = int(x[i])
        y[k][j] = y[k][j]+1
    b = [0]*120
    for i in range(len(y[k])):
            if (k==10):
                if (y[k][i]!=0):
                    b[i] = - math.log( y[k][i] )
            if (k!=10):
                if (y[k][i]!=0):
                        b[i] = -math.log( y[k][i] )-0.01*(i-k)*(i-k)
    alp = b[:]
    for i in range(len(alp)):
            if (alp[i]==0): 
                b.remove(0) 
    plt.show()
    #fy = plt.plot(y)
    ft = plt.plot(b)
plt.show()
```

Comment: "y" isn't a 2d list but only 1d. Uncomment the "print" to see.

Answer (score 0):

If you run

```
jo = [20,30,40,50,60,70]                                                        
y = [jo][0]*120                                                                 
print(y)
```

you will see that `y` is a one-dimensional list containing 720 elements, which is `120 * len(jo)`. This is because in the line `y = [jo][0]*120`, you create a nested list `[[20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]]`, then take the first element of that list, which is `[20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]` (or `jo`), and repeat it 120 times.

Since you are looking for an array of 120 rows, `len(jo)` columns, you could create this like:

```
y = [[0] * len(jo)] * 120
```

To access the elements according to your code sample, you would modify your `for` loop to also get the index of the element in `jo`, i.e.:

```
for idx, k in enumerate(jo):
    x=[]
    mo = str(k)
    migo = "".join(["./",mo,"/result_no"])
    with open(migo) as f:
        for line in f:
            x.append(float(line))
    y = [[0] * len(jo)] * 120
 #   print(y) 
    for i in range(len(x)):
        j = int(x[i])
        y[idx][j] = y[idx][j]+1
```

You may consider whether `y` is supposed to be defined inside the `for` loop - I suspect not.

Comment: ok thank you, how can I define a two dimensional array with the raw defined by jo and column of 120 zeros ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure on the structure you're describing. What do you want the array to look like?

Comment: Y is a matrix of 120 0 for every column but the column are defined by the array jo

Comment: Please see my update, which constructs a 120 row, 6 column "array" (nested list) of zeroes.  The columns are defined by the position in the list `jo`, rather than the value, since value-based access is not how we would normally use a list. To achieve that, you would need to add an extra row at the beginning and find the index of `k` within that row.